# set Multiple state Id for custom component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have implemented custom inputBox component. So When I am using this component first time then it is working fine and when I am using multiple time in one page then data is prepopulate to next component.

Custom component:

```
import React, { createRef } from 'react';

import {
    View,
    TextInput,
    Alert,
    Text,
    StyleSheet
} from "react-native";

class BoxInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {

        super(props)
        this.state = {
            digit1: '',
            digit2: '',
            digit3: '',
            ...props
        }
        this.digit1Ref = createRef()
        this.digit2Ref = createRef()
        this.digit3Ref = createRef()
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.digit1Ref.current.focus()
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.state.digit1 && this.state.digit2 &&
            this.state.digit3
           
    }
    saveText(text, key) {
        this.setState({ ...this.state, [key]: text }, () => {
            if (text) {
                key == 'digit1' ? this.digit2Ref.current.focus() : null
                key == 'digit2' ? this.digit3Ref.current.focus() : null
                key == 'digit3'
            }
            const boxInputValue = this.state.digit1 + this.state.digit2 + this.state.digit3
            this.props.onBoxInput(boxInputValue)
        });

    }
    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <TextInput maxLength={1} keyboardType={'numeric'} ref={this.digit1Ref} style={styles.boxStyle} value={this.state.digit1} onChangeText={(text) => this.saveText(text, 'digit1')} />
                <TextInput maxLength={1} keyboardType={'numeric'} ref={this.digit2Ref} style={styles.boxStyle} value={this.state.digit2} onChangeText={(text) => this.saveText(text, 'digit2')} />
                <TextInput maxLength={1} keyboardType={'numeric'} ref={this.digit3Ref} style={styles.boxStyle} value={this.state.digit3} onChangeText={(text) => this.saveText(text, 'digit3')} />
       
            </>
        )
    }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    boxStyle: {
        marginTop: 20,
        height: 57,
        width: 50,
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderColor: '#F1F5F9',
        backgroundColor: '#F1F5F9',
        fontSize: 20,
        lineHeight: 40,
        paddingHorizontal: 15,
        textAlign: 'center'
    }
})
export default BoxInput;
```

---

```
 import React, { createRef } from 'react';
    import styles from './style';
    import {
        View,
        TextInput,
        Alert
    } from "react-native";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';
    import BoxInput from "../../../../md-components/atoms/boxinput"
    
    class MPINScreen extends React.Component {
    
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                confirmMpinEnable: true,
                ...props
            }
            this.codes = [{
                value: '+91',
            }]
        }
    
        componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
            if (this.state.mpinValue.split("").length == 3 &&
                prevProps.success_msg != this.props.success_msg && this.props.success_msg == 'verified') {
                NavigationService.navigate(this.props.navigation, 'MPINVerifyOnboarding')
            }
        }
        handleSubmit = () => {
            if (this.state.mpinValue != this.state.confirmMpinValue) {
                Alert.alert(
                    "Error",
                    "MPIN is not machted",
                    [
                        { text: "OK" }
                    ],
                    { cancelable: false }
                );
            } else {
                this.props.verifyMpin({
                    "mpin": this.state.mpinValue,
                    phoneNumber: this.props.mobileNumber
                })
    
            }
        }
        mpinConfirmation = () => {
            if (this.state.mpinValue.split("").length != 6) {
                Alert.alert(
                    "Error",
                    "Please insert 6 digit mpin",
                    [
                        { text: "OK" }
                    ],
                    { cancelable: false }
                );
    
            }else{
                this.setState({
                    confirmMpinEnable: false,
                });
            }
           
        }
     
        mpinText = (args) => {
            this.setState({
                mpinValue: args,
            });
        }
        confirmMpinText = (args) => {
            this.setState({
                confirmMpinValue: args,
            });
        }
        render() {
            return (
                <>
                    <HeaderComponent backgroundColor="#E5E5E5" showLeftIcon={true} showRightIcon={false} />
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <Text style={[styles.textInfo, styles.textTitle]}>We are almost there!</Text>
                        <View style={styles.imageWrapper}>
                            <Animatable.View animation="slideInDown" iterationCount={1} style={styles.centerIconWrap}>
                                <Image style={styles.centerIcon} source={mpin_card} />
                            </Animatable.View>
                        </View>
    
                        {this.state.confirmMpinEnable ? 
                        <Text style={[styles.textInfo]}>Setup your MPIN</Text> : <Text style={[styles.textInfo]}>Confirm your MPIN</Text>
                        }
    
                        {this.state.confirmMpinEnable ?
                            <View style={styles.rowWrap}>
                                <BoxInput id="catFood1" onBoxInput={this.mpinText} />
                            </View>:
                            <View style={styles.rowWrap}>
                                <BoxInput id="catFood2" onBoxInput={this.confirmMpinText} />
                            </View>
                        }
                        <View style={styles.marginBottom}>
                            <Text style={[styles.mpinNote]}>M-PIN is a short 6-digit PIN that you have to set for</Text>
                            <Text style={[styles.mpinNote]}>our mandatory Two-Factor Authentication</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.bottomBtnSyle}>
                            <View style={styles.multipleBtnStyle}>
                                <Button onPress={this.handleBack}>{"Back"}</Button>
                            </View>
                            {this.state.confirmMpinEnable ?
                                <View style={styles.multipleBtnStyle}>
                                    <Button onPress={this.mpinConfirmation} >{"Confirm"}</Button>
                                </View> :
                                <View style={styles.multipleBtnStyle}>
                                    <Button onPress={this.handleSubmit} >{"Save & Continue"}</Button>
                                </View>
                            }
                        </View>
    
                    </View>
                </>
            )
        }
    } 
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MPINScreen);
```

[image]

when I am click on confirm button then   hide and display . But in second component data is prepopulating which i was inserted.

[image]

in this screen shot data is prepopulate but i want this empty, Because user has to insert again. but it is taking same value from previous state. how we can use multiple time same component in one page.

Answer (score 0):

General idea:

Create a property in `MPINScreen` state that is changing (incrementing) every attempt (you can call it `attempt`) and pass it as prop to `BoxInput`.

In `BoxInput` create a `reset` function (that will clean the values of the text inputs and focus the first input). On `componentDidUpdate` check if `attempt` prop changed. If true - save the new value in `BoxInput` state and call "reset".